# Searching for tutorials and books for GTK# using xamarin studio

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, gtk#

I started learning GTK# for developing win forms by using Xamarin studio. Need some one help for understanding the controls and events. 
Using of GTK Sharp signals[events] is bit difference when compared to C#[events].
I am going through the below links for understanding the things. It is better if any one share the best training materials.

[www.mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/)

[docs.go-mono.com](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=E%3AGtk.Widget.FocusOutEvent)

I am practicing for my current project.

```
protected void OnTxtUsrnmFocusOutEvent (object o, FocusOutEventArgs args)
{
    if (txtUsrnm.Buffer.Text == "abcdefgh") {
        txtUsrnm.Buffer.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

i want to know about properties and signals of **GTK# MainWindow**.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you know that asking for tutorials, books or other off site resources is considered off-topic and one of the primary reasons to close a question?

Comment: @Steve, Sorry for that, i started working on the project. i don't have time for doing R&D without any materials. If you know please help me on the same.

Comment: No. Sorry but I have no clue about that. I stumbled on your question and thought to leave my comment/advice for you. Good luck

Comment: There's some simple explanation here. not sure if this is what you need. 
https://davidsonblake.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/gtksharp/ and
http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/

Comment: It is very likely that you should start with a good GTK+ book. Search on Amazon would be a better option.

Comment: Thanks @active92, I went through the links before asking the question. i required some detailed information on events and properties.